# ZF error decorator. How to wrap error decorator into <tr><td>?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-decorators

I know that it's possible to create own decorator but I'm interested in is it possible to create it throught the standart error decorator?

I would like to get smth like this:

```
<table>
     <tr>
          <td><label></td>
          <td><input></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td><ul><li>ERROR</li></ul></td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regrettably, as of ZF version 1.11.7, only a single tag is supported when it comes to wrapping forms, form elements or individual decorators. You will indeed require a custom decorator.